# how to parse json with field of optional and variant type in Haskell?

Tags: json, haskell, functional-programming

How I can parse the input json inside this file ? https://github.com/smogon/pokemon-showdown/blob/master/data/moves.js

For the secondary and flags properties? They are optional and contains variant type.

A minimal example would be this one:

```
[
  {},
  {
    "secondary": false
  },
  {

    "secondary": {
      "chance": 10,
      "boosts": {
        "spd": -1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "secondary": {
      "chance": 30,
      "volatileStatus": "flinch"
    }
  },
  {
    "secondary": {
      "chance": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "secondary": {
      "chance": 10,
      "self": {
        "boosts": {
          "atk": 1,
          "def": 1,
          "spa": 1,
          "spd": 1,
          "spe": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "secondary": {
      "chance": 10,
      "status": "brn"
    }
  },
  {
    "secondary": {
      "chance": 50,
      "self": {
        "boosts": {
          "def": 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "secondary": {
      "chance": 100,
      "self": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "secondary": {
      "chance": 50,
      "boosts": {
        "accuracy": -1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

For your convenience, you can choose to attach this snippet to the end of the js file and run it using `node move.js`. Two valid json files will be saved to your disk. One is a list of json objects while the other is an object with string as key.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("moves_object.json", JSON.stringify(BattleMovedex), function(err) {}); // 1. save a json object with string key

var jsonList = []
for (var key of Object.keys(BattleMovedex)) {
    jsonList.push(BattleMovedex[key]);
}
fs.writeFile("moves.json", JSON.stringify(jsonList), function(err) { // 2. save as a list of json object
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

**FYI**:
If you are familiar with c++, you might find it easier to understand the same problem in this post:

[How to parse json file with std::optional< std::variant > type in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643750/how-to-parse-json-file-with-stdoptional-stdvariant-type-in-c)

Comment: What is your question? If you have code that doesn't work, we can advise you, but, in general, answering homework questions is not done on this site.

Comment: @BobDalgleish The question is the title. It is for a project, I wish it is a homework question that has answer. The problem is I am not sure whether this is doable in haskell . The boiler plate shows the way to parse simple fields, but not `optional and variant` at the same time. That js file link shows the full input.


@BobDalgleish Oh, I see! the tutorial link has `school` in its domain name!

Comment: `Data.Aeson` supports `Maybe` types for optional elements, and `GADT` types for variant values.

Comment: I dont find any GADT working code example for parsing Json, is there any tutorial available online to use it with Aeson or use it alone by implementing a json parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another attempt to your `mover.json`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}


module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Text (Text)
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- eitherDecodeFileStrict "/tmp/helloworld/movers.json" 
  case ( result :: Either String [Move]) of
    Left error -> print error
    Right ms -> print (length ms)

data Move = Move
  { num :: Int
  , accuracy :: Either Int Bool
  , secondary :: Maybe (Either Bool Secondary)
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

data Secondary = Secondary
  { chance :: Maybe Int
  , volatileStatus :: Maybe Text
  , boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  , self :: Maybe Self
  , status :: Maybe Text
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

data Boosts = Boosts
  { atk :: Maybe Int
  , def :: Maybe Int
  , spa :: Maybe Int
  , spd :: Maybe Int
  , spe :: Maybe Int
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

data Self = Self
  { boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Move where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Move
    <$> v .: "num"
    <*> (   (Left  <$> v .: "accuracy")
        <|> (Right <$> v .: "accuracy")
        )
    <*> (   fmap (fmap Left)  (v .:? "secondary")
        <|> fmap (fmap Right) (v .:? "secondary")
        )

instance FromJSON Secondary
instance FromJSON Boosts
instance FromJSON Self
```

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE**: In the code examples below, I've used a `"moves.json"` file whose contents are your minimal example above.  Except for `getMoves`, which can parse any valid JSON, the other code examples won't work on the `"moves.json"` file derived from the linked `"moves.js"` file because the format is different (e.g., it's an object, not an array, for one thing).

The simplest way of using Aeson to parse arbitrary JSON is to parse it to a `Value`:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

getMoves :: IO Value
getMoves = do
  mv <- decode <$> B.readFile "moves.json"
  case mv of
    Nothing -> error "invalid JSON"
    Just v -> return v
```

Any valid JSON can be parsed this way, and the resulting `Value` has completely dynamic structure that can be programmatically inspected at runtime.  The Lens library and `Maybe` monad can be helpful here.  For example, to find the (first) object with a non-missing `secondary.chance` of 100, you could use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

find100 :: Value -> Maybe Value
find100 inp = do
  arr <- inp ^? _Array
  Vector.find (\s -> s ^? key "secondary" . key "chance" . _Integer == Just 100) arr

test1 = find100 <$> getMoves
```

which outputs:

```
> test1
Just (Object (fromList [("secondary",Object (fromList [("chance",Number 100.0),
("self",Object (fromList []))]))]))
```

which is the `Value` representation of the object:

```
{
  "secondary": {
    "chance": 100,
    "self": {}
  }
}
```

If you want the resulting parsed object to have more structure, then you need to start by figuring out a Haskell representation that will work with all possible objects you're planning to parse.  For your example, a reasonable representation *might* be:

```
type Moves = [Move]

data Move = Move
  { secondary :: Secondary'
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

newtype Secondary' = Secondary' (Maybe Secondary) -- Nothing if json is "false"
  deriving (Show, Generic)

data Secondary = Secondary
  { chance :: Maybe Int
  , boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  , volatileStatus :: Maybe String
  , self :: Maybe Self
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Self = Self
  { boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

newtype Boosts = Boosts (HashMap.HashMap Text.Text Int)
  deriving (Show, Generic)
```

This assumes that all moves have a `secondary` field which is either `"false"` or an object.  It also assumes that lots of boost keys are possible, so it's more convenient to represent them as arbitrary text strings in a `Boosts` hashmap.  Also, this handles having the `"boosts"` directly under `"secondary"` or nested within `"self"`, since your example included examples of both forms, though maybe this was a mistake.

For these data types, the default instances for `Move`, `Self`, and `Secondary` can all be used:

```
instance FromJSON Move
instance FromJSON Self
instance FromJSON Secondary
```

The `Secondary'` newtype wrapper around `Secondary` is then used to handle `false` versus an object using a custom instance:

```
instance FromJSON Secondary' where
  parseJSON (Bool False) = pure $ Secondary' Nothing
  parseJSON o = Secondary' . Just <$> parseJSON o
```

A custom instance is also needed for `Boosts` to parse it into the appropriate hashmap:

```
instance FromJSON Boosts where
  parseJSON = withObject "Boosts" $ \o -> Boosts <$> mapM parseJSON o
```

Now, with the following driver:

```
test2 :: IO (Either String Moves)
test2 = eitherDecode <$> B.readFile "moves.json"
```

this decodes your example like so:

```
> test2
Right [Move {secondary = Secondary' Nothing},Move {secondary =
Secondary' (Just (Secondary {chance = Just 10, boosts = Just (Boosts
(fromList [("spd",-1)])), volatileStatus = Nothing, self =
...
```

By using `eitherDecode` above, we can get an error message if the parse fails.  For example, if you run this on the `"moves.json"` derived from `"moves.js"` instead, you get:

```
> test2
Left "Error in $: parsing [] failed, expected Array, but encountered Object"
```

when the parser notices that it's trying to parse a `[Move]` array but is instead finding an object keyed by Pokemon move names.

Here's the full code showing both types of parsing:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.Text as Text
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

--
-- Parse into a dynamic Value representation

getMoves :: IO Value
getMoves = do
  mv <- decode <$> B.readFile "moves.json"
  case mv of
    Nothing -> error "invalid JSON"
    Just v -> return v

find100 :: Value -> Maybe Value
find100 inp = do
  arr <- inp ^? _Array
  Vector.find (\s -> s ^? key "secondary" . key "chance" . _Integer == Just 100) arr

test1 :: IO (Maybe Value)
test1 = find100 <$> getMoves

--
-- Parse into suitable static data structures

-- whole file is array of moves
type Moves = [Move]

data Move = Move
  { secondary :: Secondary'
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

newtype Secondary' = Secondary' (Maybe Secondary) -- Nothing if json is "false"
  deriving (Show, Generic)

data Secondary = Secondary
  { chance :: Maybe Int
  , boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  , volatileStatus :: Maybe String
  , self :: Maybe Self
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Self = Self
  { boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

newtype Boosts = Boosts (HashMap.HashMap Text.Text Int)
  deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Move
instance FromJSON Self
instance FromJSON Secondary

instance FromJSON Secondary' where
  parseJSON (Bool False) = pure $ Secondary' Nothing
  parseJSON o = Secondary' . Just <$> parseJSON o

instance FromJSON Boosts where
  parseJSON = withObject "Boosts" $ \o -> Boosts <$> mapM parseJSON o

test2 :: IO (Either String Moves)
test2 = eitherDecode <$> B.readFile "moves.json"
```

Comment: The HashMap.HashMap being used in your solution is also a very good way to handle it, even though the domain knowledge shows it has limited amount of keys.

Comment: I try loading your code into ghci. getMoves is returning the json, but test1 and test2 all return 
```*Main> test2
Nothing```  How can I fix it or how can I turn the whole thing into a main module so that I can compile and run the binary?

Comment: They're returning `Nothing` because the parse is failing, probably because your `"moves.json"` is different than mine.  I should have made it clear that my `"moves.json"` contents are your 69-line minimal example, not the version generated from `"moves.js"`, which has a completely different format (for one thing, it's an object instead of an array, so `"test1"` and `"test2`" will both immediately fail to parse it).

Comment: Thanks! To clarify more I updated the javascript code snippets such that the derived `moves.json` is aligned with the minimal example now. Now the `test1`  still works, but `test2` returns `Nothing`. For reasons I dont understand, the ghci is not showing any hint about where is the parsing error? Is there any way to show where is the first parsing error?

Comment: I have attempted to adapt your solution to parse the whole json, but now parsing `accuracy` is a new problem.

@K. A. Buhr

Answer (score 1):

My attempt to the minimal sample

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}


module Main where

import Data.Text
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- eitherDecodeFileStrict "/tmp/helloworld/minimal.json"
  print (result :: Either String [Foo])

data Foo = Foo { secondary :: Either Bool Bar } deriving (Generic, Show)
data Bar = Chance
  { chance :: Int
  , volatileStatus :: Maybe Text
  , boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  , self :: Maybe Self
  , status :: Maybe Text
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

data Boosts = Boosts
  { atk :: Maybe Int
  , def :: Maybe Int
  , spa :: Maybe Int
  , spd :: Maybe Int
  , spe :: Maybe Int
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

data Self = Self
  { boosts :: Maybe Boosts
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON (Object v) = do
    sd <- v .: "secondary"  -- Parse Value
    case sd of
      Bool x -> return . Foo . Left $ x
      otherwise -> (Foo . Right) <$> parseJSON sd
instance FromJSON Bar
instance FromJSON Boosts
instance FromJSON Self
```