# How to parse json file with std::optional< std::variant > type in C++?

Tags: c++, json, option-type, variant

How can I parse nested json in c++? I am looking for a json parser that is capable of parsing nested json. Especially this field in the example json below:

`optional<variant<bool, Secondary>> secondary;`

It is type composition of `optional` and `variant`.

Though only the full example can surface the problem in a clearer way,  a minimal starting point example would be this one:

```
    [
      {},
      {
        "secondary": false
      },
      {
    
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 10,
          "boosts": {
            "spd": -1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 30,
          "volatileStatus": "flinch"
        }
      },
      {
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 30
        }
      },
      {
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 10,
          "self": {
            "boosts": {
              "atk": 1,
              "def": 1,
              "spa": 1,
              "spd": 1,
              "spe": 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 10,
          "status": "brn"
        }
      },
      {
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 50,
          "self": {
            "boosts": {
              "def": 2
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 100,
          "self": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "secondary": {
          "chance": 50,
          "boosts": {
            "accuracy": -1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Here is what I have already:

```
struct Boosts {
    optional<int> atk;
    optional<int> def;
};

struct Self {
    optional<Boosts> boosts;
};
struct Secondary {
    optional<int> chance;
    optional<string> volatileStatus;
    optional<Boosts> boosts;
    optional<Self> self;
    optional<string> status;
};

struct move_t {
    int num;
    variant<bool, int> accuracy;
    int basePower;
    string category;
    optional<string> desc = std::nullopt;
    string shortDesc;
    string id;
    string name;
    optional<variant<bool, Secondary>> secondary;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather (ab)use 'std::monostate' as the 1st type arg for 'std::variant' than to use 'std::optional' on 'std::variant'. If the variant holds monostate, it means an empty variant.
By the way, why to reinvent the wheel while 'boost::property_tree' is available?

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/property_tree.html

Comment: Looking at the full json needed to be parsed, I don't see other way around. This type works using scala and haskell, not sure it is doable in cpp in one way or another

Comment: I think, I had sort of misunderstanding about your intension. But the link provided for boost libraries should be fine.  Take a look. You can use the very same library and classes to parse XML, INI and a lesser known INFO format.

Comment: Here is one ongoing attempt using nlohmann json:
https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1910

Comment: I checked the property_tree, it is good for providing toString() method. But I dont see it as a good fit to parse json and provide static type support in compile time, e.g. being able to access the element by field in the class definition rather than accessing the filed dynamically, which could lead to error.

Comment: @Red.Wave I agree with cpchung that property_tree does not check whether the key referenced is actually in the json. If the property, say `battle` is in the json object `j`, I would like to reference it using `j.battle` rather than `j["battle"]`

Comment: @lmln u r in deep trouble: no built-in support for C++ reflection. But there are library hacks and none-std extensions.